# Aligning list-style-image with <li> text

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, html-lists

I'm struggling to get a list-style-image to align with my `<li>` text. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the piggy bank image is shown slightly higher than the text.

Here's my CSS:

```
ol.custompiggy2 {
    list-style-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Simple-piggy-bank-30.png');
}


.custompiggy2 ol>li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: step-counter !important;
}

ol.custompiggy2 {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ol class="custompiggy2">
<li><a href="#goal1">Goal 1. Live in surplus</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal2">Goal 2. Start paying yourself first</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal3">Goal 3. Begin Investing (ideally in an investment ISA)</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal4">Goal 4. Begin to live frugally</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal5">Goal 5. Get a free pay rise through your pension</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal6">Goal 6. Grasp the power of compound interest</a></li>
<li><a href="#goal7">Goal 7. Upskill yourself</a></li>
</ol>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: play with the alignment of the a inside the li

Comment: Thanks would that be: a.custompiggy2  ? Will have a play.

Comment: `.custompiggy2 a`

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. Would you know how to overlay a number on top of the image?

Comment: what number to overlay ?

Comment: According to the ordered list so 1,2,3,4 etc

Comment: use vertical-align:top; will help

Comment: you cannot use image and number at the same time ... if you want this you can instead if list-style-image add the image using pseudo element and keep the number by default

Comment: Thanks, will have a Google. I noticed this is done at: https://okdork.com/kingsumo-grow-my-email-list/ see the Taco's with numbers on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the alignment of the `a` inside the `li`. Here is an example:

```css
ol.custompiggy2 {
  list-style-image: url('https://lorempixel.com/60/50/');
}
/* You need to correct this selector*/
ol.custompiggy2>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: step-counter !important;
}

ol.custompiggy2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

li a {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custompiggy2">
  <li><a href="#goal1">Goal 1. Live in surplus</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal2">Goal 2. Start paying yourself first</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal3">Goal 3. Begin Investing (ideally in an investment ISA)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal4">Goal 4. Begin to live frugally</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal5">Goal 5. Get a free pay rise through your pension</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal6">Goal 6. Grasp the power of compound interest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#goal7">Goal 7. Upskill yourself</a></li>
</ol>
```